# () => {} Что это такое?

Tags: javascript

Наткнулся в уроках js на () => {} и не могу найти объяснение смысла этого

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то это стрелочная функция.

Comment: Стрелочная функция пришедшая с ES6, данный тип записи позволяет функции видеть переменные на одном уровне где она и написана. Проще говоря, прочитайте про стрелочные функции в JS и все встанет ясно.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Стрелочные_функции

Answer (score 0):

Это функция стрелки. 
Функции стрелок - это короткий синтаксис, введенный в ECMAscript6, который можно использовать аналогично тому, как вы использовали бы выражения функций. Другими словами, вы часто можете использовать их вместо выражений, таких как function(foo){code}.

Comment: не совсем аналогично, поведение с this разное.

Comment: поддерживаю комментатора выше, может и отличие в написании вы указали, но отличительной черты - нет